# capistrano 3 error on rake assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, capistrano3, precompile

i find out for days for this error but really stuck and the error capistrano gave were not rellay clear what's wrong:

when the capistrano run this:

```
$HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile as myapp@myIP
```

it only said:

```
Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as myapp@myIP: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: Nothing written
```

does anything had this ?

i already put on Capfile
`require 'capistrano/rails'`

and `deploy.rb`:

```
set :conditionally_migrate, true
set :migration_servers, -> { primary(fetch(:migration_role)) }
set :rails_assets_groups, :assets
set :migration_role, :app
set :assets_prefix, 'prepackaged-assets'
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, %w{public/images public/javascripts public/stylesheets}
```

Comment: probably dependency problem. Can you try to install Yarn?

Comment: i did , it was installed by globally, but when i tried to run that command without capistrano on that folder, it was work well, i dont why this is happen, i did reboot my server as well :( @Fernand